# PHP (OOP): how call a new method in every methods

Tags: php, oop

Let's say I have a Class

```
<?php

class MyClass extends OtherClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
    // some stuff
    }
    public function bar()
    {
    // some stuff
    }
    public function baz()
    {
    // some stuff
    }
}
```

Now I need to add another method, that need to be called from every other method.

```
private function run_this()
{
$mandatary = true;
return $mandatary;
}
```

I can add a simple `$this->run_this()` in every method, OK, but is it possible to add some "magic" recipient to invoke `run_this()` from every method of this class?

Comment: Not when the function is private you can't no. If it would have been public you could have decorated the `MyClass` class. Also I have the feeling you have some design issue btw if you need to do this.

Comment: I don't need private at all, I could declare public without problem (in my scenario)...

Answer (score 2):

I still reeeeally think you are doing something because you have a design issue somewhere ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), however if you insist in doing what you asked you could decorated the class:

```
class OtherClass {}

class MyClass extends OtherClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
    // some stuff
    }
    public function bar()
    {
    // some stuff
    }
    public function baz()
    {
    // some stuff
    }

    public function run_this()
    {
        $mandatary = true;
        return $mandatary;
    }
}

class MyClassDecorator
{
    private $myClass;

    public function __construct($myClass)
    {
        $this->myClass = $myClass;
    }

    public function __call($name, array $arguments)
    {
        // run the mthod on every call
        $this->myClass->run_this();

        // run the actual method we called
        call_user_func_array ([$this->myClass, $name], $arguments)
    }
}

$myClass   = new MyClass();
$decorator = new MyClassDecorator($myClass);

// will first run the `run_this` method and afterwards foo
$decorator->foo();
// etc
//$decorator->bar();
```

It's a bit hard to tell and the above works like you asked, however as stated before this is most likely not what you actually want to do.

Comment: No offence, this is awesome, but only for completion (nor for you because I am sure you know): this can even be done more easily in one class without making use of the decorator pattern (and therefore create multiple classes and pass objects). Just saying. Perhaps better keep it simple.

Answer (score -1):

Could you not use the constructor ?

```
<?php

class MyClass extends OtherClass
{
    function __construct() {
       $mandatory = $this->run_this();
    }
    private function run_this()
    {
        $mandatary = true;
        return $mandatary;
    }
    public function foo()
    {
    // some stuff
        if ($this->mandatory) {
            //true
        } else {
            //false 
        }
    }
    public function bar()
    {
    // some stuff
    }
    public function baz()
    {
    // some stuff
    }
}
```

well some variation of that.

Comment: This won't solve the problem for "run_this" will only be ran once (on object instance). But sineverba wants it be be ran every time a method is called on the object I guess. (?)

Comment: Ahh I read it as he wants to run it on the class instance but wants it available for each method :(  Surely in that case then the solution is just to call the method at line 1 within all the other methods then ?

Answer (score -2):

Not entirely sure what you want, but if you want it availabe to all child objects I would put it in other class as a protected function. That way only child objects have access to it.

```
class OtherClass {
protected function run_this()
    {
    $mandatary = true;
    return $mandatary;
    }
}

class MyClass extends OtherClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
    $mandatory = $this->run_this();
    // some stuff
    }
    public function bar()
    {
    $mandatory = $this->run_this();
    // some stuff
    }
    public function baz()
    {
    $mandatory = $this->run_this();
    // some stuff
    }
}
```